# HOW TO translate CURL command to Python

Tags: python, curl

I was wondering how i can translate the following Curl command to Python:

> curl -G -H "Accept: application/json"
>   'http://mydomain.com:8080/experimental/events' --data-urlencode
>   'query=["=", "certname", "myserver"]'

I tried the following 2 options (1: using httlib and 2: using urllib2):

***Option 1: using httlib***

```
import httplib, urllib
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('mydomain.com', 8080)
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
values = {"query": "['=', 'certname', 'myserver']"}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
connection.request('POST', '/experimental/events', data, headers)  
response = connection.getresponse()
```

it is not working but it works if I do a simple request without data (urlencode) such as
connection.request('POST', '/facts/myserver', None, headers)

notes: '/experimental/events' needs --data-urlencode BUT '/facts/myserver' doesn't need --data-urlencode

***Option 2: using urllib2***

```
import urllib2, urllib
values = {"query": "['=', 'certname', 'myserver']"}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
url_path = "http://mydomain.com:8080/experimental/events"
server_request = urllib2.Request(url_path, data)
server_request.add_header('Content-type', 'Accept: application/json')
server_response = urllib2.urlopen(server_request)
```

it is not working but AGAIN, it works if I do a simple request without data (urlencode) such as
    url_path = "http://mydomain.com:8080/facts/myserver" and then
    server_request = urllib2.Request(url_path)

notes: '/experimental/events' needs --data-urlencode BUT '/facts/myserver' doesn't need --data-urlencode

**I'M STUCK WITH THIS KIND OF --data-urlencode 'query=["=", "certname", "myserver"]'**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried printing your `data` string to see if it looks how you'd expect? You can probably get curl to dump it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `curl` command is doing a GET:

```
$ curl -v -G -H "Accept: application/json" 'http://example.com/experimental/events' --data-urlencode 'query=["=", "certname", "myserver"]'
* About to connect() to example.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 192.0.43.10... connected
> GET /experimental/events?query=%5B%22%3D%22%2C%20%22certname%22%2C%20%22myserver%22%5D HTTP/1.1
[...]
```

From [the manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> -G, --get
>
> When used, this option will make all data specified with -d, --data or --data-binary to be used in an HTTP GET request instead of the POST request that otherwise would be used. The data will be appended to the URL with a '?' separator.

But the Python versions are doing a `POST`. Does it work if you do a `GET`?

```
url_path = "https://.../events?" + data
server_request = urllib2.Request(url_path)
```

The only other difference between the two is that Python is encoding spaces as `+` and `curl` is using `%20`. They should be treated identically, but if your server is badly written it could be the cause of your problem:

```
import urllib2, urllib
values = {"query": "['=', 'certname', 'myserver']"}
data = urllib.urlencode(values)
print(data)
```

> query=%5B%27%3D%27%2C+%27certname%27%2C+%27myserver%27%5D

Answer (score 0):

Interesting how `Curl` and `Python` are encoding the spaces, both results should be  identically. **GOOD CATCH!**

I replaced the values to

> values = {'query': '["=", "certname", "myserver"]'}

then generated what `Curl` and `Python` are encoding and still seeing Python is encoding the spaces as `+` (don't like this)

`Curl`

> query=%5B%22%3D%22%2C%20%22certname%22%2C%20%22myserver%22%5D

`Python`

> query=%5B%22%3D%22%2C+%22certname%22%2C+%22myserver%22%5D

I "fixed" the issue using the `Curl` one and hardcoding the query on the url as follow (the code is not elegant but it is working now :-) )

```
import httplib
connection = httplib.HTTPConnection('mydomain.com', 8080)
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
connection.request('GET', "/experimental/events?query=%5B%22%3D%22%2C%20%22certname%22%2C%20%22" + myserver + "%22%5D", None, headers)
response = connection.getresponse()
```

[Brendan Long](https://stackoverflow.com/users/212555/brendan-long) Thank you again!